# How do I easily convert a fuzzy pixel art image back into pixels?

Tags: image-format, pixel-art

I want to convert a fuzzy pixel art image into a crisp actually-pixel-art pixel art image.

An example of this is taking a still from say a youtube clip of a pixel-art animation, and recreating the image, given there are no known raw images available of the original artwork.

Disregarding any copyright issues (this is for personal use only), what's the easiest way to convert this fuzzy pixel art back into something that could resemble the source image?

I've attempted a manual conversion, but I'm having issues with trying to workout what scale I'm working in, and the original colour of each pixel.

e.g., given this:

> [image: fuzzy]

how can I programatically convert it back to this:

> [image]

Comment: Kind of confusing :|  please  Post image

Comment: Sorry, I want a sure fire way of doing this in the future. Nutshell: Take pixel-art animation that has been bastardised by youtube, and convert back into the nice pixel stills, thus removing jpeg artifaction, blowing up of image, taking it from say 5-to-1 ratio to 1-to-1 ratio for pixels.

Comment: The only real solution is to pick the pencil tool and get to redrawing/touching-up by hand. Alas, there's no magic filter for this. JPG/MPG is lossy compression. By definition you've lost image data that you're not going to get back.

Comment: Does the original artwork use a fixed palette of say 16 colours? I think that would make things a lot easier.

Comment: @DA01: make your comment an answer and I will vote it up. I completely agree with that.

Comment: JPG/MPG is lossy compression, but that doesn't mean it can't be reversed; you might still need to touch up by hand, but an automated process might save significant time. I think this scenario is a good candidate for this and I could imagine an algorithm averaging pixel colour values over several frames in order to derive a best guess of the underlying palette.

Comment: Also, this is quite an interesting challenge, would you be able to link to a sample video clip?

Comment: @e100 I want to take samples from this: www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXIzyquw-kc Preferably the raft and beach panning shot, to be able to recreate that (hopefully) as a woolen tapestry. I've tried contacting the video producer to no avail, in the hope of sourcing original stills.

Comment: Hmm, not quite as simple and clean-edged as I'd hoped looking at your original "cube" illustration!

Comment: <s>First, clear it up by posterizing it. Then, you can use [Pixel Art Scaling Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_art_scaling_algorithms), if you want to upscale. Downscaling should be trivial.</s> This doesn't seem to work as well as I thought. Another option would be to scale it down to something like 16x16, record all the colors into a palette, then round the colors in the original image to the nearest color in the palette. Not sure how to do this in practice, but it's possible. You may want to convert it to a .GIF first, BTW.

Comment: It's easiest to download the video (at highest quality possible), then make sure your media player is playing it at a nice resolution (100%, usually).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per Philip's request, I'll turn this into an answer:

The only real solution is to pick the pencil tool and get to redrawing/touching-up by hand. Alas, there's no magic filter for this. JPG/MPG is lossy compression. By definition you've lost image data that you're not going to get back.

Others have suggested some automated ways that could help, for sure, but they are hardly programmatic. Whether it's the pencil tool or playing with curves, or posterizing, it's all going to need to be done by hand to ensure it's doing what you want it to do.

That said, if this is an animation, and you get get one frame looking fairly well in PhotoShop, then record the actions in PhotoShop and then you could batch process the rest of the frames.

I still think you'll have to go in frame-by-frame though to get it the way you want.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't been very clear about your exact goal. I think you want to do two things: clean up the compression artifacts, then downscale the image while maintaining crispness.

For the compression artifacts, there are lots of [JPEG recovery utilities](http://www.google.com/search?q=fix+jpeg+compression) that produce pretty good results, though not perfect, and I don't know how well they work with pixel art.

If those don't work for you, you'll need to touch up your images by hand with something like an eraser tool.

After you've fixed the JPEG compression, just downscale your image the way felixthehat described.

> I'm having issues with trying to workout what scale I'm working in

To figure that one out, zoom your image about 800% in Photoshop. At that point, a grid appears. By looking at that grid, you can figure out the size of every upscaled square pixel. And that tells you the scale factor.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but have you tried scaling it in photoshop using Image Size with Nearest Neighbour (preserve hard edges) selected in the Resampling dropdown? That gives you a lossless size increase...
[image]

Comment: Useful information to be sure, but not really what the OP asked for.

Comment: +1 to counter the downvote. OP's example pics show he wants downscaling, not just JPEG recovery.

Comment: yes, but this answer is about upscaling.

Comment: Its actually about downscaling. at least the images in the question are clearly NOT upscaling.

Comment: It's downscaling in the question and its image; it's upscaling in your answer and its image.

Comment: @e100: Ah, my bad.